# Like button with Ajax

Tags: python, ajax, django, python-3.x

I am trying to create a like button with ajax.

This is my architecture:

**models.py**

```
class Comentario (models.Model):
    titulo = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    texto = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    autor = models.ForeignKey (Perfil, null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    fecha_publicacion = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    tag = models.ManyToManyField(Tags, blank=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(null=True)
    likes = models.ManyToManyField(Perfil, blank=True, related_name="likes")

    def __str__(self):
        return (self.titulo)

    @property
    def total_likes(self):
        return self.likes.count()

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.slug = slugify(self.titulo)
        super(Comentario, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

**views.py**

```
def like(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        perfil = request.user
        slug = request.POST.get('slug', None)
        comentario = get_object_or_404(Comentario, slug=slug)

        if comentario.objects.filter(id=user.id).exists():
            comentario.likes.remove(user)

        else:
            comentario.likes.add(user)


    contexto = {'likes_count': comentario.total_likes }
    return HttpResponse(json.dumps(contexto), content_type='application/json')
```

**urls.py**

```
url(r'^like$', login_required(like), name='like'),
```

**html**

```
<input type="button" id="like" name="{{ company_slug }}" value="Like" />
<script>
$('#like').click(function(){
      $.ajax({
               type: "POST",
               url: "{% url 'home:like' %}",
               data: {'slug': $(this).attr('titulo'), 'csrfmiddlewaretoken': '{{ csrf_token }}'},
               dataType: "json",
               success: function(response) {
                      alert(response.message);
                      alert(' likes count is now ' + response.likes_count);
            },
                error: function(rs, e) {
                       alert(rs.responseText);
            }
      }); 
})
</script>
```

When I push the button like it does not do anything. The console tells me:

POST htt jquery.min.js:4 p:/127.0.0.1.8000/home/like/404 (not found)

and: http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js

What is the problem?

Comment: I have edited the code

Answer (score 0):

**#1**

As I can see you use `jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js`. This (slim) version excludes ajax module!

https://blog.jquery.com/2017/03/16/jquery-3-2-0-is-out/

> **Slim build**
>
> Sometimes you don’t need ajax, or you prefer to use one of the many
>   standalone libraries that focus on ajax requests. And often it is
>   simpler to use a combination of CSS and class manipulation for all
>   your web animations. Along with the regular version of jQuery that
>   includes the ajax and effects modules, we’ve released a “slim” version
>   that excludes these modules.

**#2**

You use wrong url as I can see. 
In your **html** part it's `{% url 'home:listar' %}`, given **urls.py** contains only `name='like'`

Comment: And how can I use jQuery with Ajax??

Comment: Use full (not slim) build, for example https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js (check <script ...> in your templates)

Comment: I have made the change and the error has dissapeared but the button does not still work... I think that the AJAX part is not correct

Comment: Need more data! Is url correct? I see you use `home:listar` url name, but your like button has `like` name

Comment: check whether the post request URL is matching up to the URL you've defined in the browser dev tools network panel

Comment: The goal is to return to home:listar url after pushing the like button, thats why I put that. Due to I have no created a template for home:like, if I put that it tells me that it is impossible to find. Do you know any good tutorial to create like button in django easily?

Comment: Hmmm... you must send data to `home:like` and then do .. redirect? But in this case why you use ajax? We usually use ajax unless we want reload the whole page

Comment: because I need to click like and refresh the page with the total of likes.

Answer (score 0):

Put JQuery script before ajax code:

```
<script src="jquery.js"></script>
$('#like').click(function(){
      $.ajax({
               type: "POST",
               url: "{% url 'home:listar' %}",
               data: {'slug': $(this).attr('name'), 'csrfmiddlewaretoken': '{{ csrf_token }}'},
               dataType: "json",
               success: function(response) {
                      alert(response.message);
                      alert(' likes count is now ' + response.likes_count);
            },
                error: function(rs, e) {
                       alert(rs.responseText);
            }
      }); 
})
</script>
```

Comment: I had already added it in base.html, where this template inherit. So, I do not think it is the problem..

Comment: can u show the code where you connecting jquery in template?

Comment: try to use just jquery and pure html without bootstrap and pooper.js, your code is okay, if it won't work try to connect jquery cdn

Answer (score 0):

function interested(postId) {
$.ajax({
type:"post",
url:"/userInterested?postId="+postId,
data:postId,
success: function(data){
console.log(data);
if (data == '1') {
$("#8").addClass("active");
};
}
});
}

Comment: Please format your code so that it would be readable.